# How to do string concatenation efficiently in C++?

Tags: c++, string

I have a single string that i need to do a couple of concatenations to. This is my first time dealing with strings in cpp and the methods I need to use seems to be taking a char* and not std::string. this is what i need to do:

```
String folderpath = "something";
folderpath +="/"+dbName;
mkdir(folderpath);
foo(folderpath + "/" +dbName + ".index");
bar(folderpath + "/" +dbName + ".db");
```

This is how i've managed to do it in C++ and it looks so bad. Is there a better way?

```
char* folderPath = getenv("CAVEDB_ROOT_FOLDER");
strcat(folderPath, "/");
strcat(folderPath, dbName);
mkdir(folderPath);
char* indexfile;
char* dbfile;
strcpy(indexfile, folderPath);
strcpy(dbfile, folderPath);
strcat(indexfile, "/");
strcat(indexfile, dbName);
strcat(indexfile, ".index")
strcat(dbfile, "/");
strcat(dbfile, dbName);
strcat(dbfile, ".db");
foo(indexfile);
bar(dbfile);
```

Comment: All those `strcat` calls invoke *undefined behavior*, so that is certainly not a solution. And `std::string` has a `c_str()` function which returns a `const char*`

Comment: There is buffer overwrite in all `strcat`.

Comment: Just use `std::string` and its `operator+`. Or `std::stringstream`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::string` has a `c_str()` method for getting a `const char*` pointer, eg:

```cpp
std::string folderpath = "something";
folderpath += "/" + dbName;
mkdir(folderpath.c_str());
folderpath += "/" + dbName;
foo((folderpath + ".index").c_str());
bar((folderpath + ".db").c_str());
```

That being said, in C++17 and later you should use the functions and classes in the [`<filesystem>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) library (in earlier versions, you can use [boost::filesystem](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) instead), eg:

```cpp
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

fs::path folderpath = "something";
folderpath /= dbName;
fs::create_directory(folderpath);
folderpath /= dbName;
folderpath += ".index";
foo(folderpath.string().c_str());
folderpath.replace_extension(".db");
bar(folderpath.string().c_str());
```

Comment: Ah c_str solves most of my issues. Also thanks for mentioning filesystem.